# Is it possible to modify variables in an executable without symbol tables in GDB?

Tags: c, gdb

I've been told it is possible, but it seems every time I try I continuously get an error saying "No symbol tables have been loaded." Have I been tricked, or is it in fact possible?

Comment: did you compile the binary with -g option? `gcc -g test.c`. How is gdb going to know the variable names without symbol tables?

Comment: No, I was told you can do it without -g by using "disas main" and modifying the addresses where the variables are stored.

Comment: and how do you find the address?

Comment: Knowledge of x86 assembly I suppose. For instance, I found the value of the variable without the symbol table, but now I want to change it.

Comment: so  you found the address of the variable? just set that address with using pointer?

Comment: How do I do that through GDB?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70658/discussion-between-hunter-watkins-and-milind).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the address of the variable is `0x7fffffffe51c` and its type is `int`, here is how you do it in GDB:

```
(gdb) set {int}0x7fffffffe51c = 11
(gdb) p *0x7fffffffe51c
$5 = 11
```

To find local variables, refer to
"[How to read local variables with gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959503/how-to-read-local-variables-with-gdb)".